# Is a relation between the empty sets a function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Say we define a relation: $R_f\colon\varnothing\leftrightarrow\varnothing$. The definition for a relation to be a function, for any relation between $A$ and $B$, is $∀a ∈ A : ∃!b ∈ B : afb$. Does that mean that the previously defined relation between two empty sets is a function? As the "for all $a$ in $A$" part comes first and there are no $a$ values, does the "there exists a unique $b$ in $B$" part ever get checked?

Comment: There are no relations between $\phi$ and $\phi$, because the only subset of $\phi \times \phi$ is $\phi$, which is obviously a function (bijection if you like).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: The empty set is a perfectly good relation between $\varnothing$ and $\varnothing$. It is one of the special relations we call _functions_, but that doesn't stop it from still being a relation, too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point. I forgot that functions are special relations. All right, so $\phi$ is  the only relation between the empty sets, and it also has the property of being a function and a bijection, in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- as you correctly argue, the *empty function* (represented by the empty set of pairs) is a good function $\varnothing\to\varnothing$. It is the only function that has $\varnothing$ as its codomain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every relation with $\emptyset$ on the "left" side is - vacuously - a function. (Where "every relation" is in fact just one relation, the empty relation)